# Django DateFilter - input_format change

Tags: django

I need to change input format just for one field. I need to accept 31/03/2020 instead of 3/31/2020.
If I enter 3/31/2020 then it's works, but when try 31/03/2020 then appears **Enter a valid date.**
This can be done global by DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS but I'm looking for the way where input_format will apply only to one field.

This is what I currently have.

view.py

```
def customer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customer.order_set.all()
    order_count = orders.count()

    myFilter = OrderFilter(request.GET, queryset=orders)
    orders = myFilter.qs

    context = {
        'customer': customer,
        'orders': orders,
        'order_count': order_count,
        'myFilter': myFilter
    }

return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html', context)
```

filter.py

```
class OrderFilter(FilterSet):

    start_date = DateFilter(field_name="date_created", lookup_expr='gte')

    class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ['product',  'status', 'note', 'start_date']
```

customer.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form method="get">
            {{ myFilter.form }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I tried to add **init** object to the class but without success.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_date = DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'])
```

Comment: should "input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y']" accept an entry like "31/03/2020" ?

Comment: OK i give wrong example. It not accept 31-03-2020